# Need help to create a rangeslider MAUI C#

Tags: c#, slider, maui, rangeslider

Im trying to create a rangeslider for my application in MAUI C#. There is no default rangeslider in Maui library so I tried to make my own rangeslider in a very simple way. It works kind of fine but when I drag the left or right slider the thumbs tend to move a little bit in the GUI, and I of course don't want that. Can anyone help me?

P.S. Im kinda of a noob.

Here is my code:

```
public class DoubleSlider : ContentView
    {
        Slider sliderLeft;
        Slider sliderRight;
        double totalWidth;

        Grid grid;


        public DoubleSlider(Slider left, Slider right) 
        {
            //initialize sliders
            grid = new Grid();
            this.Content = grid;
            sliderLeft = left;
            sliderRight = right;

            //Make the right slider slide from right to left
            sliderRight.Rotation = 180;


            //Add events
            sliderLeft.DragStarted += OnLeftDragStarted;
            sliderRight.DragStarted += OnRightDragStarted;

            sliderLeft.DragCompleted += OnLeftDragCompleted;
            sliderRight.DragCompleted += OnRightDragCompleted;

        }
        public void SetSize(double width) 
        {
            //Set size
            grid.WidthRequest = width;
            totalWidth = width;

            //Left slider width
            sliderLeft.WidthRequest = totalWidth;

            //make some headroom so the user can press the thumb
            sliderRight.WidthRequest = totalWidth - 20;

            //Move up the slider a tiny bit so it looks that the sliders are in sync
            sliderLeft.TranslationY = 1.1;

            //Left slider start from left
            sliderLeft.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

            //Right slider start from right
            sliderRight.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;

            //Maximum values
            sliderLeft.Maximum = totalWidth;
            sliderRight.Maximum = totalWidth - 20;

            grid.Add(sliderLeft);
            grid.Add(sliderRight);

        
        }
        public void OnLeftDragStarted(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Slider slider = sender as Slider;

            //When drag started, give the slider the total width and maximum value
            slider.WidthRequest = totalWidth;
            slider.Maximum = totalWidth;

        }
        public void OnRightDragStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Slider slider = sender as Slider;

            //When drag started, give the slider the total width and maximum value
            slider.WidthRequest = totalWidth;
            slider.Maximum = totalWidth;
        }
        public void OnLeftDragCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Slider slider = sender as Slider;

            //When drag is completed, give the width and maximum the slider value
            slider.WidthRequest = slider.Value;
            slider.Maximum = slider.Value;

            //And minimize the other sliders width and maximum
            sliderRight.WidthRequest = totalWidth - slider.Value;
            sliderRight.Maximum = totalWidth - slider.Value;

        }
        public void OnRightDragCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Slider slider = sender as Slider;

            //When drag is completed, give the width and maximum the slider value
            slider.WidthRequest = slider.Value;
            slider.Maximum = slider.Value;

            //And minimize the other sliders width and maximum
            sliderLeft.WidthRequest = totalWidth - slider.Value;
            sliderLeft.Maximum = totalWidth - slider.Value;


        }
    }
```

This is how it looks which is fine but when I drag the left or right thumb the other one tends to move a bit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQQ0x.png)

Comment: Post how you use the control as well.

Comment: I think that's because you drag the slider and change the property at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Using two `Slider` to build a `RangeSlider` should quickly produce some strange visual behaviors. Especially when reading this advice from the [official MAUI doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/slider?view=net-maui-8.0):

> Warning Do not use unconstrained horizontal layout options of Center, Start, or End with Slider. Keep the default HorizontalOptions setting of Fill, and don't use a width of Auto when putting Slider in a Grid layout.

Your best bet is to build one using platform specific controls, or try something custom using standard MAUI components. To do so put two `Frame` in a `Grid` and adjust horizontal position (along X coord) using `PanGestureRecognizer`.
Here's my take on that (definitely needs more testing, but it's a good start), check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MarcAlx/4e54edf67dc4a95d373f3d99e4a9d523).